# Where write the code for an add-in outlook

Tags: jquery, outlook-addin

I try to understand add-in development in Outlook. And I’m real confuse about all code example I could read. I would like to know how create different button and linked my button to my own code.

For the moment, my reference is this Github https://github.com/OfficeDev/outlook-add-in-command-demo and the part “How's it all work?”
First question, document said
“The URL to the HTML file with all of the JavaScript code for the button is specified in the FunctionFile element (note that it uses the resource ID specified in the Resources element):

```
<FunctionFile resid="functionFile" />”
```

I understand, when I click on my button, one function is run. And this function is located… well I don’t know, how I can find my function?
After I have

```
  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
    <FunctionName>addDefaultMsgToBody</FunctionName>
  </Action>
```

The type ExecuteFunction is predefine somewhere? There is a list?
And again I don’t understant the function addDefaultMsgToBody? Where is it? How I can write my own function?

Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after lot of try I understand the logic.

In fact I have in tag resources all resid used to use my files and my fonction. I have create a button and when I click on my own function is run